# Verifying a hashed password

Tags: php, hash, salt, verify, crypt

**UPDATED**

I have updated to PHP5 based on recommondations, I still can't figure out how to verify a password

Here is the `password_hash` script that enters the password into a field which is a varchar (255) field. (a username is also inserted). This all inserts data as to what I think it should IE the username and a long random code for the password.

```
  $options = array(
    'cost' => 12 // the default cost is 10
  );
  $ex_password = password_hash($_POST["ex_password"], PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
```

then I use the following on my login form

```
$sql = "SELECT ex_username, ex_password FROM exhibitormain WHERE ex_username=:ex_username LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare ( $sql );
$stmt->bindValue( ":ex_username", $ex_username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->execute();
$user = $stmt->fetch();
$userExists = $stmt->fetchColumn();
if(!empty($user)){
  if (hash_equals($_POST['ex_password'], $user['ex_password'])) {
      echo 'Password is valid!';
  } else {
      echo 'Invalid password.';
  }
}else{
    echo '<p class="error">No such username found.</p>';;
}
```

What Im trying to do is check that the username exists and if it does then compare that the password is correct.

If I enter a username that isn't in the database I follwos the correct path and shows 'No such username found.' error message but when I type in a username that does exists where I get the password right or wrong it always sends me down the path that shows the erro 'Invalid password.'

Any help Apprecieted.

Ian

Comment: Consider using the password_hash and password_verify functions. They are a lot easier to use. Also, what do you mean you are willing to upgrade to PHP 5? Are you running 4 right now?

Comment: yeah using 4.2.7.1, its an old server and they arnt using php5

Comment: Looks like you simply reversed the order of the arguments to `crypt` while checking.

Comment: Realistically, you should upgrade to at least version 5.6 of PHP. Ideally, you should upgrade to version 7.x for the *'latest and greatest'*. It is much faster as well. There are new functions available since PHP 5 that will cut down your code considerably (built in functions like those mentioned by @Evert). Your code is also **VERY** susceptible to SQL injection. You should look at using `PDO`:http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php to access your database (or any other method that uses prepared statements like `mysqli_`:http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: use `hash_equals` function to compare look at php crypt first example : [http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)

Comment: Hi Guys, I have updated my question after taking the step to use php5 and hash_equals, but still not quite working. could you have a look

Comment: Ahhhh I have already spotted it! I changed hash_equals to password_verify and it works. Is the password_verify a good route to take?

Comment: @snookian - Yes the `password_verify()` is the correct way to check a password against a stored hash. The function `hash_equals()` is named a bit misleading, it just compares two strings with constant time to avoid timing attacks and cannot be used to verify a salted password hash.